# set Cassandra.yaml for replication with network topology strategy

Tags: cassandra-2.1

I want to use Cassandra as a distributed DBMS.I have installed Cassandra on Windows(10) and Ubuntu (via VMware on Windows). How can I insert a record and replicate it into another DB?
The base problem is set Cassandra.yaml
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, add the seed nodes in the cassandra.yaml file:

> seed_provider
>   (Default: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider ) A list of comma-delimited hosts (IP addresses) to use as contact points when a node joins a cluster. Cassandra also uses this list to learn the topology of the ring. When running multiple nodes, you must change the - seeds list from the default value ( 127.0.0.1 ). In multiple data-center clusters, the - seeds list should include at least one node from each data center (replication group). See Initializing a multiple node cluster (single data center) and Initializing a multiple node cluster (multiple data centers).

Also make sure that your node is reachable from outside your local machine by setting the listen_address:

> listen_address
>   (Default: localhost ) The IP address or hostname that other Cassandra nodes use to connect to this node. If left unset, the hostname must resolve to the IP address of this node using /etc/hostname, /etc/hosts , or DNS. Do not specify 0.0.0.0.

After you restarted the nodes, check via the nodetool that they are up, running and connected, using "nodetool status".

If all of this is ensured, you can connect either via cqlsh and insert data or you can use a driver for e.g. java/scala and connect to the cassandra cluster for inserting data. If you want to have it replicated, you need to set the replication factor, when you are creating the keyspace.

I advise you to check the free online courses for Cassandra which cover completely your questions and show you how easy you can get started with Cassandra: https://academy.datastax.com/courses/